# how to populate nested array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-populate

assuming i have this 2 schemas
company schema with an array of categories

```
//category
export const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: { type: String },
}, { timestamps: true });
//company
export const CompanySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    name:String,
    email:String,
    categories:{type: [CategorySchema], default: [] },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

product schema with category as a ref to the category from company

```
export const ProductSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    category:{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category' },
}, { timestamps: true })
```

is it possible to populate category from the product ?
i tried this code and it's not working

```
const products=await this.productModel.find({}).populate({'path':"category","model":"Category"}) ``
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code for `populate`

```
const products=await this.productModel.find({}).populate({'path':"category","model":"company.categories"})
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is just

```
productModel.find({}).populate("category")
```

Comment: this returns null in category since it's a nested document

Comment: can you type the first letter Capital if not try it